# Entity Framework: Eager loading is acting like lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have bunch of entities and they are associated with each other. For example: I have Student entity and student has bunch of Books. 
When I try to load the student by saying:

```
dbContext.Students.FirstOrDefault()
```

it works fine. I can see the generated sql query and it is trying to load just Student. And when I try to read the Books property of the student it is executing another query to get the books. Which is correct. Now I would like to load the student with it's backpacks in one call with the following query:

```
dbContext.Students.Inclide("Books").FirstOrDefault();
```

it is generating SQL script to get both student and books. Which is correct, but When I read the Books property of the student it is making another call to the DB to get the books. I tried to reproduce it on a smaller project, but it works on that test project. What I am I doing wrong that eager loading is not working in my production project? It is really complex to post the code that has problem.

Comment: Have you disabled lazy loading in your DataBase Context?

Comment: @papadoble151 no. I thought using Include will just bring it as eagerly. In my test project I haven't disabled the LazyLoading and using Include works fine.

Comment: When the error was not reproducable in a simple test project, then the error must be something related to the project... Maybe something is wrong with the DbContext or the Students entity. Could you add the code of these to your post? (Including any fluent configurations if any)